# How to convert the few jSON value within an array to HTML table and return as JSON itself in groovy

Tags: groovy

I am new to groovy , so please help me here , how to achieve the below req. The below is the Input jSon array, I want to write Groovy/JS to loop over and form html tags for fields within "Organization"

```
[
{
"Organization_Role_Assignments_group" : [
  {
    "Organization" : "Global",
    "Organization_Type" : "Location Hierarchy",
    "Role_Name" : "Business Process Adviser"
  },
  {
    "Organization" : " Technology)",
    "Organization_Type" : "Supervisory",
    "Role_Name" : "Manager"
  }
],
"NT_Name" : "Test",
"Badge_ID" : "2",
"AttachmentLink" : "<br /><a xml=\"lang\" href=\"https:">Click here to 
view </a>"
}
 ]
```

From the above I need to create HTML HTML table and return as JSON value

```
[
  {
  "Value" :
   "
<table style="width: 100%;" border="1"><tbody><tr><td style="width: 30%;font-weight:bold;font- 
size:100%;">Role Name</td>
<td style="width: 50%;font-weight:bold;font-size:100%;">Organization</td>
<td style="width: 25%;font-weight:bold;font-size:100%;">Organization Type</td>
</tr><tr><td style="font-size:90%;">Manager</td>
<td style="font-size:90%;">1</td>
<td style="font-size:90%;">Cost Center</td></tr><tr>
<td style="font-size:90%;">Cost Center Manager</td>
<td style="font-size:90%;">3</td><td style="font-size:90%;">Cost Center</td></tr><tr>
</tr></tbody></table><br>

<a href="URL">
Click here to view</a>
",
"User_Name":"Test",
 "URL":"someURL"
}]
```

I am able to generate output using the below script: However the data is split into two elements and I need it in one :

```
String HTML_ORGANIZATION_TABLE_HEADER = "<table style=\"width: 
100%;\" border=\"1\"><tbody><tr><td style=\"width: 30%;font- 
weight:bold;font-size:100%;\">Role Name</td><td style=\"width: 
50%;font-weight:bold;font-size:100%;\">Organization</td><td 
style=\"width: 25%;font-weight:bold;font-size:100%;\">Organization 
Type</td></tr>";
    String HTML_TABLE_ROW_START = "<tr><td style=\"font- 
  size:90%;\">";
    String HTML_TABLE_CELL = "</td><td style=\"font-size:90%;\">";
    String HTML_TABLE_ROW_END = "</td></tr>";
    String HTML_TABLE_FOOTER = "</tbody></table>";
    String EMPTY_STRING = "";
    String HTML_NEW_LINE = "<br>";      
                StringBuilder tableBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                
                
                // Add table Header
                tableBuilder = 
 tableBuilder.append(HTML_ORGANIZATION_TABLE_HEADER);
                // Add rows for each history entry
  tableBuilder =  tableBuilder.append(HTML_TABLE_ROW_START).append(Role_Name).append(HTML_T ABLE_CELL)
                            .append(Organization).append(HTML_TABLE_CELL).append(Organization_Type).append(HTML_TABLE_ROW_END);
                

                // Add table Footer
                tableBuilder = tableBuilder.append(HTML_TABLE_FOOTER);
                
                // Add hyperlink to attachment
                if (AttachmentLink != null && !AttachmentLink.equals(EMPTY_STRING)) {
                    tableBuilder = tableBuilder.append(HTML_NEW_LINE).append(AttachmentLink);
                }

val = tableBuilder.toString();
```

The output which I am getting is:

[
{
"NT_Name" : "Test",
"AttachmentLink" : "<table style="width: 100%;" border="1"><td style="width: 30%;font-weight:bold;font-size:100%;">Role Name<td style="width: 50%;font-weight:bold;font-size:100%;">Organization<td style="width: 25%;font-weight:bold;font-size:100%;">Organization Type<td style="font-size:90%;">Business Process Adviser<td style="font-size:90%;">Global<td style="font-size:90%;">Location Hierarchy
<a xml="lang" href="https://">Click here to view >"
},
{
"NT_Name" : "Test",
"AttachmentLink" : "<table style="width: 100%;" border="1"><td style="width: 30%;font-weight:bold;font-size:100%;">Role Name<td style="width: 50%;font-weight:bold;font-size:100%;">Organization<td style="width: 25%;font-weight:bold;font-size:100%;">Organization Type<td style="font-size:90%;">Manager<td style="font-size:90%;"> Technology (1000503320)<td style="font-size:90%;">Supervisory
<a xml="lang" href="https://">Click here to view"
}
]

Comment: What have you tried? How did it not work? If you show us how far you got, we can suggest ways to fix it

Comment: @tim_yates Updated the question, please check